# Linear Algebra - Invertible matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this problem and I'm not sure my solution is correct.

Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix, defined over the real numbers, A is not invertible matrix.

Proof that there's is $B \neq 0$ and $C \neq 0$ that $AB=0$ and $CA=0$

**My solution**

Since A not inverible the equation $Ax=0$ has a non-trival solution therefore the homogeneous equation has infinite solutions.

- $B=(x1,...,x_n)$ while $(x_1,...,x_n)$  is solution for the homogeneous equation therefore Ax=0 $\rightarrow$ AB=0.
- Lets choose C as a not invertible matrix (meaning that the homogeneous equation has infinite solutions) and choose that any vector in $A$ is  a solution for the homogeneous equation therefore $Cx=0$ has infinite solution and A is a solution for it meaning $Cx=0 \rightarrow CA=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, $B\ne 0$ and $C\ne 0$ are required.

1. For the case $B$, it is basically right. But what are $x_1,\dots,x_n$? Well, as you said, $Ax=0$ has a nontrivial solution, say $x_1$, then we can also choose $x_2=\dots=x_n=0$ (or $=x_1$, doesn't matter).
2. If $A$ is not invertible, then neither is $A^T$. (Can you reason this?) So, applying 1. to $A^T$ we find a nonzero $C_1$ matrix such that $A^TC_1=0$, then let $C:=C_1^T$.

Comment: Yes, forget to mention that $B \neq 0$ and $C \neq 0$ by $(x_1,..,x_n)$ I mean a solution vector such as $(1,2,3,...x_n)$ I should mark these as greek letter instand my bad.

on case 2, I don't sure I got it, Is this always true $AB=0 \rightarrow B^{-1}A=0$